# How to calculate Sobel Edge Detection in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am just using TensorFlow to calculate the Sobel Edge maps for a tensor A with the shape of [16,96,96,1] (16 is the batch size, 96 is the image block size, 1 is the number of channel (only consider luminance channel here)).

I found that in TensorFlow, there is a function called 'tf.image.sobel_edges' which can return the edge maps for each channel. For this function, it returns the tensor with the shape of [16,96,96,1,2]. I do not understand the meaning of the last 2 dimensions..... My understanding is that the edge maps should be a binary image, so that the output should be [16,96,96,1], but the output of this function is [16,96,96,1,2]...... If I only want to obtain the edge energy of image, how could I do from the output of this function?

Could you please explain this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is because the edges are computed along the X-axis and the Y-axis (i.e horizontal and vertical edges). I think you're looking for the image gradients when you say "edge energy". Use this function instead: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/image_gradients
 and compute the RMS of the returned tensors

Comment: @ma3oun, thanks for your help! May I ask if I got tensor of [16,96,96,1,2] from the 'tf.image.sobel_edges' function, how could I get the final binary edge image? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [tf.image.sobel_edges](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/sobel_edges) documentation indicates that the returned tensor contains the gradient components of the image along the horizontal axis and the vertical axis, in the case of a single channel image. In order to compute the magnitude of that gradient and obtain the *edge energy image*, we merely need to compute the square root of the sum of these components, as such:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()

img = tf.random.normal(shape=(16,96,96,1),dtype=tf.float32) # replace with your image data

grad_components = tf.image.sobel_edges(img)

grad_mag_components = grad_components**2

grad_mag_square = tf.math.reduce_sum(grad_mag_components,axis=-1) # sum all magnitude components

grad_mag_img = tf.sqrt(grad_mag_square) # this is the image tensor you want
```